# Riemann surface Logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I would like to show, that the Logarithm gives a Riemann surface. Therefore I define the set $M:=\{(z,w)\in D \vert \ f(z,w)=0 \}$ with $D:=ℂ^*\times ℂ$ and $f(z,w):=e^w-z$.

Afterwards I will use the following Theorems (I don't prove them now), which I'm going to mention here:

**Theorem 1**: Let $U\subseteq ℂ²$ open, $f:D\rightarrow ℂ$ a holomorph function and $M:=\{(z,w)\in U \vert \ f(z,w)=0 \}$ the corresponding zero set. If $f$ is nonsingular and $M$ is connected, then $M$ is a Riemann surface.

**Theorem 2**: Let $X$ be connected, $F:X\rightarrow Y$ a continuous function. Then $F(X)$ is also connected.

Now I'm going to prove that $M$ is a Riemann surface. 
Obviously $f$ is holomorph and for all $p=(z,w)\in M$, because of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z,w)=-1\neq 0$ the function $f$ is nonsingular. We can write the set $M$ as $M=\{(z,w)\in D\vert \ e^w=z\}=\{(e^w,w)\vert \ w\in ℂ\}$. Now have a look at the function $F:ℂ \rightarrow D, \quad F(w):=(e^w,w)$. This function $F$ ist continuous, as each component of the function is continuous. As $ℂ$ is obviously connected, with **Theorem 2** we get, that $F(ℂ)=M$ is also connected. All conditions for **Theorem 1** are now fulfilled and that's why $M$ is a Riemann surface.

So my questions are:

1. Is this proof true?
2. Does this proof really show, that that $M$ is the Riemann surface of the logarithm?
3. Does the Riemann surface look like this [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannsche_Fläche#/media/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannsche_Fl%C3%A4che#/media/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg) or like this http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RiemannSurfaceOfTheLogarithm/ and why?

Thank you very much! :)